# MySQL: Sorting rows from 2 (or more) tables by their columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to sort data from different tables by its time..
I have tables:

**books:**
book_id | book_name | book_time

**movies:**
movie_id | movie_name | movie_time

And I want to select the latest books and movies together. I would like to sort it like: ORDER BY book_time DESC
But for both tables. I tried it with joins but it wasn't very good and it was slow too.

Comment: I don't understand how you would join these tables; they have no relation.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Maybe the movies database are movies that were based off of books and the movie_id is a foreign key for the book_id. Although I suspect this is not the case...

Comment: @PhpMyCoder: Especially since that's better expressed as a M2M.

Comment: That was only example. My tables have nothing with books/movies. Joining was bad idea, I know :) But now I've got answer. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually try to stay away from subqueries, but if you put the union into one, you can easily order by time:

```
SELECT id, name, time
FROM
(
    SELECT book_id id, book_name name, book_time time FROM books
    UNION
    SELECT movie_id id, movie_name name, movie_time time FROM movies
) booksandmovies
ORDER BY time DESC;
```

Comment: +1: But I'd consider using `UNION ALL` instead - it's faster because it doesn't remove duplicates (which `UNION` will).  Sure, some books & movies have the same name but are unlikely to have the same ID and time...